# (Eclipse oxygen/Linux) linker C/C++ RAM usage

Tags: c++, linux, linker, arm

At company we use Eclipse CDT to compile our embedded project. With all compilation options projects is really big and linking takes great amount of time and RAM memory.

I have 8GB RAM and 8GB swap linux partition. Sometimes during linking 4GB of swap is used! After this OS is hardly working and I have to reboot PC.  Is there any solution to limit linker RAM usage?

(Compiling mixed C/C++ project. Using gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q1-update toolchain.)

My linker

```
arm-none-eabi-ld --version
GNU ld (2.26-4ubuntu1+8) 2.26
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Comment: Eclipse does not have any linker. It uses external compiler and tools. Actually Eclipse itself could be quite RAM hungry, I typically rise heap limit for Eclipse itself to at least 8 Gb so it won't crash as often. As for linking RAM problem, you can try switching to Single Compilation Unit build (though this may be quite time consuming).

Comment: OK. I've added information about my toolchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My currently solution to not reboot PC, after a heavy build when swap usage increased :

- disable all RAM consuming applications,
- do commands :

:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo swapon -a
```

At least I don't have to reboot PC.